# How to manage clusters with foreman/puppet

Tags: puppet, foreman

I need to deploy i.e. three distinct Zookeeper clusters. Each server inside a cluster should be configured to know what its ID is (and create a myid file). Also every Zookeeper server needs to know a list of all of the servers in the cluster with their corresponding id.

Is there a way to only configure this in one spot per cluster? Define a server is supposed to run Zookeeper, in cluster 'QA' and has id 4. This information will be used to

- identify if a server needs to run zookeeper classes
- write the correct id to the myid file
- add the server with the correct id to all other zookeeper nodes and update them / restart them

I am pretty new to foreman and didn't see how this could be done. Is foreman the wrong tool for this and should I use plain puppet and code similar to [Automatic Cluster Membership with Puppet](http://techblog.constantcontact.com/devops/automatic-cluster-membership-with-puppet/)?